# Raytracing: Ray/Triangles intersection 3D (back-face culling problem)

Tags: c, raytracing

I'm developing a raytracer engine in C. So far, things works right, but when I move the camera around a 3D object like a Triangle, it disappears when the camera goes to the another "180 degree range" regardless of X or Y.

Everything works properly while I'm "facing" (front of) the triangle. But when I go around with the camera, like walking in a circle around the object, as I get behind, it no longer draws it, unless I go back.

Intersection Code:

```
static int ray_checkTriangleIntersection(Ray *ray, Triangle *t, double *distance) {
    Vector3 pvec, tvec, qvec;
    VEC3_CROSS(pvec, ray->direction, t->edges[0]);
    double det = VEC3_DOT(t->edges[1], pvec);
    if (det < EPSILON) {
        return 0;
    }
    VEC3_SUB(tvec, ray->origin, t->a);
    double u = VEC3_DOT(tvec, pvec);
    if (u < 0.0 || u > det) {
        return 0;
    }
    VEC3_CROSS(qvec, tvec, t->edges[1]);
    double v = VEC3_DOT(ray->direction, qvec);
    if (v < 0.0 || u + v > det) {
        return 0;
    }
    double d = VEC3_DOT(t->edges[0], qvec);
    double inv_det = 1.0 / det;
    d *= inv_det;

    *distance = d;
    return 1;
}
```

I don't quite understand why this is happening, I think the order of the 3 points doesn't matter.

Comment: It sounds like you have face culling enabled (a standard optimization for rendering images).  What rendering libraries are you using, if any?

Comment: I'm using SFML. ( more precisely -> CSFML).
The program not use any GPU acceleration, all done with math, in C.
To put it simply: 2 for cycle goes through the screen X-Y, and find if there is intersection with an object, then the color isdetermined by the material-light-angle and ambientCofficient shadows etc..

Comment: Otherwise, it seems that if I reverse the order of the points, the visibility will also be reversed. If I swap the coordinates of a triangle (VectorA3 VectorB3 VectorC3) (VectorB3 VectorA3 VectorC3) it will look the same but it will be visible from the back, not from the front. It has to do with the intersection code.

Comment: For what it's worth, the behavior you're describing sounds like what you want when rendering a triangle (it's pretty unusual to render both sides of a triangle).  If you want to disable this, I think getting rid of the statement `u < 0.0` in the second if statement will do so.  I'm using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling for reference.

Comment: As a correction, you might also have to get rid of `v < 0.0`.  Sorry for not being more certain; I'm not super comfortable with the vector math here.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work out. In fact, it has a very nasty end result, distorting the entire triangle.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this back-culling check is built into the algorithm you're using.  I don't have time to work out the correction myself, but that's the approach I think will work.  Sorry about that; hope someone else can help!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, i think so too, this is more than just delete a statement. This is my first-ever raytracer program, so I'm just experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`if (det < EPSILON)`
to:
`if (fabs(det) < EPSILON)`

Comment: Results the same. Even if i completely remove that if statement, the problem remains.